# promise reject not working with mysql error

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to get return an mysql data using promises and it works, but when I try to create an error in mysql on purpose but then I am getting this error .

```
(node:28464) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Users not found
(node:28464) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I checked everywhere and it says to use .catch but its odd that I am using catch but cannot figure out the problem. Normally I would like to know how to solve this instead of just continuing without knowing the right way.

This is the model..

```
getAllUser =
     new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query('SELECT * from users', function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error){
                return reject('Users not found');
            }else{
                resolve(results[0]);
            }
        });
    });
module.exports = {
    getAllUser
};
```

And here is how I am calling the model, the model in the top should return an error since the mysql table is called `user` not `users`.

```
router.get('/db',(req,res,next)=>{
    getAllUser.then((result)=>{
      console.log(result);
    }).catch((e) => {
       console.log(e);
    });
});
```

Comment: try "reject" instead of "return reject"

Comment: @RobertRowntree I did, did not work, after that tried return

Comment: @RobertRowntree its weird, I tried so many different ways, but still same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in your model file. Function which return promise should be created instead Promise.

Working code:

Model:

```
getAllUser = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.query('SELECT * from users', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error){
            return reject('Users not found');
        }else{
            resolve(results[0]);
        }
    });
});
module.exports = {
    getAllUser
};
```

Router:

```
router.get('/db',(req,res,next)=>{
    getAllUser.then((result)=>{
      console.log(result);
    }).catch((e) => {
       console.log(e);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!! I couldn't figure it out for a very long time, Thank you! Dint know about returning a promise via function.
Thanks again!